# What is the maximum theoretical efficiency of heat to electricity conversion?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, electricity, thermoelectricity

I know that heat engines (heat to kinetic) are limited by Carnot cycle and that kinetic energy to electric energy conversion via standard generator reaches over 90%.

However I would like to know wheter Carnot cycle limits every kind of thermal to kinetic/electric energy like thermocuoples? If not then what is the limit of such conversion?

Also what is the highest possible efficiency of Carnot cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know whether Carnot cycle limits every kind of thermal to kinetic/electric energy like thermocouples?

Yes, since any conversion of heat into "work" is limited by Carnot, as you said:

> I know that heat engines (heat to kinetic) are limited by Carnot cycle.

> Also what is the highest possible efficiency of Carnot cycle?

The [maximum efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_Engine#Efficiency) of a Carnot cycle is given by:

$$
\eta_{max} = 1- \frac{T_c}{T_h}
$$
Where $T_c$ is the temperature of the cold sink and $T_h$ is the absolute temperature of the hot source.

> kinetic energy to electric energy conversion via standard generator reaches over 90%.

This is not limited to Carnot since it is not a heat engine (converting heat to work). Photo voltaic solar cells are also not heat engines since they convert light not heat.

This paper is titled "[Nanoscale Heat Engine Beyond the Carnot Limit](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5935)" However it is a theoretical paper and the system has not been built, it may not be possible to construct as described or behave as described, or a new nanoscale Carnot description may be needed.

If some process were to beat the Carnot limit it would be possible to reduce global entropy. This would violate [the second law of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics) and is believed not to be possible, Stephen Hawking and Leonard Suskind "invented new physics" just to ensure that black holes would not violate this principle. See [the black hole war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Hole_War).